# Using GPIO pins as software I2C pins and finding analog value of those pins

Tags: i2c, atmel, gpio, comparator

I am using AT32UC3C microcontroller which has 64 pins. I am using gpio pin PB01 as SCK and gpio pin PA04 as SDA and ticking then manually high and low. These pins are configured as GPIO_OPEN_DRAIN and GPIO_DIR_OUTPUT.
I have connected this controller to MPU9150 sensor connecting pin PB01 to SCK and PA04 to SDA of the sensor.What I observed on oscilloscope is when I read accelerometer values from MPU9150 the SDA line high voltage is 3.3V and low voltage is 0.24V. But when I see the voltage on SDA line while accessing magnetometer of MPU9150 the lower value goes up to 1.68V. The sensor is sending data and acknowledging to microcontroller but microcontroller doesn't treat 1.68V as logic low. So all register values are read as 1.
Can I solve the problem without changing the hardware? I mean if I define a new threshold value for logic high and logic low level and say that if voltage is above 2V consider it logic high else logic low. Is it possible.

The datasheet of AT32UC3C says:

**PIN__GPIO__PIN TYPE_______GPIO FUNCTION**

```
                                      A             B                 C
```

PA04----4-----------x1/x2-----------ADCIN0-----USBC-ID-----AC1FA0-ACAOUT

Can I use Analog comparators to compare the value of this pin to some other pin whose voltage is 2V and instead of reading digital gpio value I assign 0 when voltage is below 2V and 1 if voltage is above 2V.

Or is my configuration wrong. Can I used open drain mode for gpio pins with dir_output mode? If my configuraton is wrong what should be the correct configuration.

Or is there any other way to solve the problem? Please tell me if you need any other information. Thanks in advance.[image: MICROCONTROLLER SCHEMATIC][image: MPU9150 CONNECTION SCHEMATIC]

I would like to share 1 more fact. When I read acc and gyro, Auxiliary SDA and Primary SDA  as well as Auxiliary SCL and Primary SCL read exactly the same voltage levels.(seen on oscilloscope). But when I read magnetometer, Auxiliary SCL and Primary SCL read the same but Auxiliary SDA and Primary SDA has a difference.When I see Auxiliary SDA, I can find that voltage toggles between 3.3V to 0.6V(MPU9150 is able to pull down volatge to 0.6V) but when I see primary SDA, voltage toggles between 3.3V to 1.68V. Auxiliary SDA and SCL pins are left open(not connected anywhere in my circuit) whereas communication is done vis Primary SDA and SCL lines.

I would also like to add something about MPU9150 sensor.It is actually a combination of 2 sensors MPU6050(acc and gyro) and AK8975(magnetometer). SDA and SCL of MPU6050 are connected to primary SDA and SCL while SDA and SCL of AK8975 are connected to auxiliary SDA and SCL of MPU9150. AK8975 can be accesses by 2 methods. First is bypass enable method,where Primary and Auxiliary SDA gets shorted. Second is Master mode of MPU9150 where MPU9150 is master to sensors connected on Auxiliary SCL and SDA i.e. even to AK8975.
I am using method 1 right now and what I have mentioned in above paragraphs are problems faced by me in method 1. I have still not implemented method 2.
[image]

Comment: It seems to me that a better solution would be to find out why your magnetometer isn't pulling the I2C lines low properly.

Comment: Sounds like an issue with improper pull-up resistors selection.

Comment: Seconded. Your pullups are too strong.

Comment: There may be a problem with the ground connection to the magnetometer.

Comment: Snap of MPU9150 schematics section will help

Comment: I am connecting 4.7kOhm pull up resistors to SDA and SCL line.

Comment: In the schematic of MPU9150 breakout board by sparkfun, I was able to access magnetometer via primary SCL and SDA line. But there the pull up resistors were of 10kOhm. Else no difference between that circuit and the circuit used by me.

Comment: I need to confirm if this is the problem or the problem is with configuring GPIO pins to open drain and directional output simultaneously. As I had posted a question in avr freaks about gpio configuration and they replied that gpio pins cause a problem while pull down when both these pins are used with this configuration.@IgnacioVazquez-Abrams

Comment: I have replaced that 4.7Ohm by 10kOhm but it is still not working. In case of magnetometer it is pulling it down only to 1.68V. Not even change observed in that lower value!!

Comment: Question is modified@IgnacioVazquez-Abrams

Answer (score 2):

I'd need a schematic to see for sure, but my first suspicion is that you have *series* resistors on the MPU9150 I2C lines. I've seen this in a mistaken effort to address posisble EMI issues. I2C shouldn't have series resistors; it's all very slow edge rates and with strong enough pullups it's possible that the series resistor is high enough resistance and dropping enough voltage to cause this issue.

If you can paste a schematic that includes the AT32, MPU9150 and **EVERYTHING** connected to the I2C pins we can definitely help you with this. There is no need to try to do I2C with the analog comparator functions on the microcontroller, although I will admit this is a novel solution to your problem.

Comment: I have added the schematic

Comment: Zooming the page to view image will help

Comment: @KuldeepSoni Why on earth do you have four MPU9150s with a common clock and individual data lines? This is not a normal I2C connection.

Comment: I am doing sensor fusion from the data of those 4 IMU's. Every sensor has some inaccuracy. To combat that and make the data much more accurate, I am doing this. I have seen significant improvement by collecting and fusing data from 4 sensors. Since I want data from all the sensors at the same time, I have a common clock. So I am doing parallel communication. @akohlsmith

Comment: If you're going to do that use for independent I2C buses; don't try to clock them all synchronously and read back 4 data lines. Sure you might get it to work eventually but do it the easy way.  Follow the credo: Get it working, then get it good. Early optimization is the way of wailing and gnashing of teeth. :-)

Comment: Okay I will do it and then get back to you soon.

Comment: @KuldeepSoni great. Basically you should be able to talk to any ONE MPU9150 without trouble. Once that is working and you want to try doing some fancy synchronous reading by sharing the clock line you can try it, but get it working the simple way first. :-)

Comment: I tried it with 1 IMU. And the observation remains the same. So the problem is not with 4 IMU's connected via common SCL line. I was able to access magnetometer using sparkfun's breakout board and arduino and it worked. There I was using dedicated I2C pins. Here gpio configured in the way mentioned in the post. So what is the problem then? I have added schematics to the question. Please have a look at it.

Comment: Is the pasted schematic EXACTLY what is on the board? Do you have a picture of the board?

Comment: Picture of board is added.

Comment: Those photos aren't at all helpful. :-) Ok... so now the next thing to do is to measure with a scope the signal at the micro and the same signal again at the MPU9150. My suspicion is still that there is a resistance in the line and the voltage drop is occurring over that.

Comment: Are you sure that both master and slave aren't driving the bus simultaneously? You have to set the master SDA to high-impedance when reading slave values.

Comment: While Initialization I have set the pin to be in (GPIO_OPEN_DRAIN | GPIO_DIR_OUTPUT) configuration.Both these configurations are used when gpio pin is a output pin. But while reading , pin is an input pin. But still this configuration works for acc,gyro.I have also implemented this configuration on another gpio pin and have accessed pressure sensor. But in case of magnetometer which is present in MPU9150 voltage at SDA pin is pulled down only to 1.68V while at auxiliary SDA it is pulled down to 0.6V.And according to bypass mode these pins should be shorted which happens in accelerometer case.

Comment: @avl_sweden Will that mean that both master and slave are driving bus simultaneousy? If so while reading, I should change the configuartion of the pin.

Comment: @akohlsmith I have checked that. They read the same(voltage on micro and on SDA). The auxiliary SDA and primary SDA are shorted in bybass mode in case of acc and gyro but this is not happening in case of magnetometer. I have already posted difference in their waveforms in form of an image.

Comment: Your schematic and description do not agree. Please post an accurate schematic. You mention that SDA of the primary and secondary are shorted, but your schematics do not reflect this. It's difficult to help when we have incomplete/incorrect information. ONE schematic page, as a CLEAR picture or PDF would be greatly beneficial. Even zoomed up the text on the pictures is small.